# Odd recurring noise

Tags: 7.0-nougat, lg, lg-g5, custom-sounds

I have an LG g5 running Android 7.0. every now and then, several times per day, my phone makes a sound that belongs to no alert (that can be seen on screen at least). As best as I can describe it - it's like a mailbox opening and mail being taken out and the door being closed. It began a week ago and I cannot think what is causing it. What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: I have a BlackBerry KeyOne running Android 7, and I also experience this frequently. It seems like it happens when I am connected to public Wi-Fi connections that require me to agree to terms of service, but I'm not sure if that's just a coincidence. The only way I can stop the noises is by putting my phone on silent.

Answer (score 1):

I also frequently experience this, and in my case I discovered that the source of the noise was the NFC tags that restaurants embed in the table for use with table tracker devices. It seems that my phone beeps whenever it picks up an NFC signal. There might be a way to shut off the noise, but I haven't found it.